# How can I merge array's items?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array ( [0] => array("red","green"),
               [1] => array("blue","yellow")
             );
```

And this is expected result:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )
```

---

See? I want to merge all items of `$arr` *(which are also array themselves)*. How can I do that?

I can do a loop on it and then use `array_merge()` every time like this:

```
$res = [];
foreach ( $arr as $item ) {
    $res = array_merge($res, $item);
}
```

[It works as well](https://3v4l.org/ML4tY). But I guess I can write it better. Any idea?

Comment: Post is best suited for code review, maybe. Definitely not SO

Comment: @DarylGill Not suited for Code Review either. Please take a look at their [help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making such recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do trick with `call_user_func_array`:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);
```

This trick is possible, because `array_merge` accept dynamic arguments count.

Answer (score 0):

You declare array in wrong way:

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array("red","green"),
               1 => array("blue","yellow")
             );
```

The error reported by PHP says it clearly:

```
Fatal error: Illegal offset type in /in/Hhfqa on line 3
```

Line 3 in your example is exactly line of first array element.

Please check http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

It's a style exercise, but if the structure remains the same as in your example, you can play with this:

```
$arr = array ( '0' => array("red","green"),
               '1' => array("blue","yellow")
             );

$res = explode(",",str_replace(array('[',']'),'',json_encode($arr)));
```

Hope this helps.